# How to pass common arguments in Dart?

Tags: dart

Say, I have:

```
callback.orderBy('foo', reverse: true).localToThis();
callback.orderBy('foo', reverse: true);
```

You can see in both callbacks, I am passing same arguments,

```
'foo', reverse: true
```

Is there any way I can make them something (a variable or a method) so that I can use something like this:

```
callback.orderBy(common).localToThis();
callback.orderBy(common);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```dart
> callback.orderBy('foo', reverse: true).localToThis();
> callback.orderBy('foo', reverse: true);
> ```

If you're calling the same function with the same set of arguments, if the function has no side-effects, you might as well just save the result and avoid calling the function again.

If the function does have side-effects or if you want to call the function with only some of its arguments the same, you could use a [partial function application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) to bind arguments:

```dart
final orderBy = () => callback.orderBy('foo', reverse: true);
orderBy().localToThis();
orderBy();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class, containing fields you want to be common

```dart
class OrderConfiguration {
  final String orderBy;
  final bool reverse;

  OrderConfiguration(this.orderBy, {reverse = false});
}
```

and then accept an instance of `OrderConfiguration` as an argument to `orderBy`

But you can do this only for your own functions, for functions that weren't written by you, you could make a wrapper function. (May be this is a better option for your function too)

```dart
void orderCallback(callback) {
  callback.orderBy('foo', reverse: true);
}
```

or if `orderBy` returns a value

```dart
Type orderCallback(callback) {
  return callback.orderBy('foo', reverse: true);
}
```