# How to return a value of int from a method that is created using Function?

Tags: dart

Say, I have:

```
int Function(int x, int y) add() {
  return x + y; // Error
}
```

---

PS: I know I can use

```
int add(int x, int y) => x + y;
```

but I want to use a `Function` here, you may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62083727/12483095) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62083562/12483095) thread to get an idea what is the main requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning a function but the result of `x + y`. You need to do this instead:

```
int Function(int x, int y) add = (x, y) {
  return x + y;
};
```

Which can be used like a normal function:

```
print(add(1,2)); // 3
```

This will make `add` a variable to a function which takes two `int` arguments and returning the sum.

Or if you want to have a method which returns a method:

```
int Function(int x, int y) add() {
  return (x, y) {
    return x + y;
  };
}
```

Which are used like:

```
print(add()(1,2)); // 3
```

With the last example you can do something like this to construct a function based on input to e.g. have some default parameters you want to set one time:

```
int Function(int x, int y) add(int alwaysAdd) {
  return (x, y) {
    return x + y + alwaysAdd;
  };
}

void main() {
  final addMethod = add(10);

  print(addMethod(1,2)); // 13
  print(addMethod(5,5)); // 20
}
```